# How to use NavigationStack with HStack?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I'm trying to create a window similar to this one:
[image]

Where I have the list on the left, and once an option is selected, I change the view on the right side. But I don't know how to change the view on the right when the NavigationLink is clicked. Is NavigationLink even the right way of doing that?

```
import SwiftUI

struct SettingsView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack{
            NavigationStack {
                List {
                    Section("General") {
                        NavigationLink("Applications", value: "app")
                    }
                    Section("Calendar") {
                        NavigationLink("Outlook", value: "outlook")
                        NavigationLink("Google", value: "gCalendar")
                    }
                }
                .navigationTitle("Settings")
                .listStyle(.sidebar)
                
            }
            VStack{
                // How to change this once the item is clicked?                    
               ApplicationsView()
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}


struct ApplicationsView: View{
    var body: some View{
        Text("Applications")
    }
}

struct OutlookView: View{
    var body: some View{
        Text("Outlook")
    }
}

struct SettingsView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SettingsView()
    }
}
```

Comment: The window you are showing is not an `HStack` it looks like a `List` with `NavigationLink`s for rows. For iOS 16+ Use a `NavigationSplitView` with a `NavigationStack` in the second/detail column then a `List`. It is a pretty basic setup. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/migrating-to-new-navigation-types

Comment: Question is tagged `macOS`, but `NavigationSplitView` will work there too.